# How to have an absolute v-overlay boxed inside a v-col?

Tags: css, vue.js, css-position, vuetify.js

When an absolute `v-overlay` is used inside a `v-col`, the overlay covers all of its grandparent `v-row` instead of just its parent `v-col`.

> "absolute overlays are positioned absolutely and contained inside of their parent element."
>
> -Vuetify's documentation

Here's a [demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/ztickm/pen/ZEbdNYO?editors=1100)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because elements are by default have a position value of `static`, and in CSS there's this rule:

> absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).
>
> Source: [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

In our case the nearest positioned ancestor is the `v-row`.
To fix this, one has simply to add a `position: relative;` to the parent `v-col` (you can uncomment this in the codepen to see the difference)